# tuple' object has no attribute 'append' while it's not a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to write a code that creates a dictionary where the keys are star ratings (from * to *****), and the values are a list of restaurants. Each restaurant is stored as a tuple containing the restaurant name and a phone number.
Ex: (‘Trilye’, 312 447 12 00)

The point is, I can't manage creating a dictionary of keys with multiple restaurant names (It overrides each star rather than multiple restaurants) and got an error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'` while trying to append a value to a key - which is not a tuple. How can I fix this issue and add multiple elements to a single key?

file line example: *****,Trilye,312 447 12 00

my code:

```
rests = open('/Users/berketurer/Desktop/restaurants.txt', 'r')
rests_dict = {}

for line in rests:

    data_name = ()
    data_number = ()    
    index1 = line.find(",")
    number = line[len(line)-14:len(line)]
    data_name += (line[index1 + 1:len(line) - 14],)
    data_number += (number,)

    key = line[0:index1]
    if key in rests_dict:
        rests_dict[key].append((data_name,data_number))
    else:
        rests_dict[key] = data_name,data_number

print(rests_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

that's because the key creation right term *is* a tuple

```
 rests_dict[key] = data_name,data_number
```

you'd need

```
if key in rests_dict:
    rests_dict[key].append((data_name,data_number))
else:
    rests_dict[key] = [(data_name,data_number)]
```

But the best way would be to create

```
rests_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)  # import collections first
```

in the first place so no need to test if key exists, just append:

```
rests_dict[key].append((data_name,data_number))
```

if key doesn't exist, an empty `list` is created instead of `KeyError`

Comment: still got the same error after changing the if else block, error seems to be seen right after running the if part - without jumping to else block.

Comment: not possible. There aren't any tuples in the dictionary now. Try the defaultdict approach to avoid any typos.